Can Argo rollouts be used with Istio in ingress mode (without a service mesh, etc.)?
We are using Istio for K8S ingress (gateway) in order to proxy traffic to subsets etc., we don't inject the service mesh sidecars. Is this compatible with Argo Rollouts traffic shaping via Istio? The corresponding documentation mentions "mesh" multiple times.
